# NatTable maximum column width

Tags: java, nattable

We are using the NatTable and we are executing the InitializeAutoResizeColumnsCommand on it. Hence the columns will be automatically resized based on its contents.

Actually our problem is that we have some data which are too long, hence we would like to use the mentioned InitializeAutoResizeColumnsCommand but with a static maximum column width setting.

I can't figure out how it could be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is to implement a custom `AutoResizeColumnCommandHandler` and register it instead of the default one. And in that implementation you ensure a max value. NatTable API itself has no configurable option for that.

Comment: Could you provide an example how the custom one should look like ? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry I meant `AutoResizeColumnCommandHandler` ... and copy the existing code and use `Math#min()` with the gridColumnWidth and the maximum size you want. https://github.com/eclipse/nebula.widgets.nattable/blob/master/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.core/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/grid/command/AutoResizeColumnCommandHandler.java

Comment: Thank you, it is working. Note: the mentioned command AutoResizeColumnCommandHandler is processed just on the columns which are actually visible and it's not processed on the columns which are not visible. I've succeed to solve this by a small "hack", the handler's doCommand will apply the configured size to all of the columns even if it's processed once.

Comment: As long as you don't have huge data sets that is fine. For huge data sets (which NatTable was designed for) it would have negative impact on the performance.